# Batch Download of Files in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, file, http, download

In my application I need to download automatically many files via HTTP, possibly quite large. I want to implement something like "batch" behavior, when all files that need to be downloaded are put into a queue, then several work threads pick up tasks from this queue and do the actual download in parallel in background. Also I need some usual behavior from download managers: handle incomplete or failed downloads, use temp folder/file name until the file is fully downloaded, etc. I tried googling, but I was surprised I did not find anything useful in Java to help in this task. The only things I've found so far were:

1. [Download manager in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1654790/download-manager-in-java) - No useful answers, just one link to
2. http://luugiathuy.com/2011/03/download-manager-java/ - this one is better, but still very low level, too simple and does not cover 90% of my needs. Seems more like tutorial and less like library
3. http://sourceforge.net/projects/jdm/ - despite its name, it's even more basic.

Does anybody know any other libraries that can implement such behavior?

Answer (score 0):

The *library* that you can use is [apache http components](http://hc.apache.org/) - it gives you a nice API for working with HTTP.

But you'd have to implement the rest yourself - batch downloading is effectively just a single download repeated many times. For that you'd need a separate library that implements. You can easily use the java 5 concurrency additions, e.g. `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(..)` to submit `Runnable`s that perform the downloads.

I'd suspect there is no ready-to-use implementation, because it would be an end-user product, rather than a library. You'd have to gather the components yourself.

Comment: I don't agree with you that this would be an end-user product. For me this seems like very common task. There are so many common things for any application that needs to download files using a queue. It would be pity if I had to implement this myself. Not that I don't like coding myself, I just don't like reinventing the wheel. HTTP Components is way to basic for this task, I need something more similar to traditional download manager, but without GUI. Let's see if somebody finds another solution.